# My Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt shortcut was deleted

Tags: visual-studio-2010, command, command-prompt

Can I create a new one? Can someone tell me where it points to ?

Thank you

Comment: Why the negative votes? Seems like a valid question to me. Looking at the answers, it's hardly a trivial link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My shortcut's target is:

> %comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86

My Start directory is:

> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\"

Answer (score 2):

Per the target of my shortcut:

%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86

and the main exe target...

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

Answer (score 2):

The target for mine is:

`%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86`

Answer (score 2):

%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86

That's on a 64-bit system.